# Flask : How to serve static files from under the template directory?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, assets

i use Flask and want to change my assets folder directory.Here's my folder structure:

```
/python
   /static
     /js
     /img
     /font
     /css
   /templates
     /default
       /css
       /js
       /img
   /venv
   app.py
```

I want to move all the folders under static folder `(js,css,font,img)` under to the folder `default`.
But when i do this my css files and the others(`js etc.)` can not be loaded the page.Should i set a property to my application?
I also tried this one:

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_path="/templates/default")
```

But could not make it.Is there another way to do this?Thanks a lot.

**Update:**
When i remove the leading slash in the line above (`static_path="templates/default"`) got this error `ValueError: urls must start with a leading slash` 
with the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 17, in <module>
    app = Flask(__name__,static_path="templates/default")
  File "/Users/ozcan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 481, in __init__
    view_func=self.send_static_file)
  File "/Users/ozcan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 63, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ozcan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in add_url_rule
    rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
  File "/Users/ozcan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 550, in __init__
    raise ValueError('urls must start with a leading slash')
ValueError: urls must start with a leading slash
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem; have you figured out a solution?

Comment: I used Flask-Themes extension and handled my problem

Comment: Is it not app = Flask(__name__,static_folder="/templates/default")?

Comment: i've just had a similar problem and eventually solved it like that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29521067/303114 (i believe its a good way since it's custom way and you have more programmatic control on which static files you serve)

Answer (score 8):

It should be static_folder not static_path while initializing app.

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_folder="/templates/default")
```

In templates:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/file.js')}}"</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to change static file with `app.config['static_folder']='foo'` or something else

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I misread your original directory output. You need to put `templates` IN the `static` directory, as that's where Flask looks for static data by default.

Comment: i put templates to the static folder now got this jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

Comment: you put them in `static/templates/<templat_name>` or `static/<template_name`? The first version is correct.